# Spring Boot 2: Using external Property-Files

Tags: spring-boot, properties, external, executable-jar

I have a executeable jar what I want to configure by properties outside of the jar. What works fine is `application.properties`, when putting it to `config` folder close to the jar. But I have a second property-file what seems not to be picked up and I would like to have the best practice for that.

The folder `config` looks like:
[image]

In the config-folder you will find:
[image]

Both property-files are also in the `src/main/resources` folder.

My StartClass looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("migration-shrink.properties")
public class MigrationShrinkApplication implements CommandLineRunner {}
```

My bat file looks like:

```
java -jar migration-shrink-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.config.location=./config/migration-shrink.properties
```

I wanted to separate Spring-Configuration from Application-Configuration, thats why I have two different property-files.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@PropertySource` annotation is not necessary.

As of Spring Boot 2.0, you can declare additional locations with:

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=./config/migration-shrink.properties
```

Keep in mind that those additional locations are searched before others, so values can be overridden in the other locations.

See [the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: Hey Brian, thank you for your answer, `-Dspring.config.additional-location` was very helpful and it works, especially I only need to put properties into external config files what makes sense for a user to config, the other properties are set in the `src/main/resources` by default. 

The `@PropertySource` for the `migration-shrink.properties` I still need. Removing it has the effect, that the properties are not found. So if you remove the hint with the `@PropertySource` I will give you the check.

Comment: Wait - are those additional properties mapped to a Spring Boot Configuration properties class? Or are those used by `@Value` annotations?

Comment: few are used with `@Value`